# TaffyDB, error says TAFFY is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, taffydb, taffy

I'm working on a web-based game with HTML, CSS & JavaScript, using Visual Studio. I'm using TaffyDB as a database. However, whenever I try to create a database using the function TAFFY, an error shows up on the console, saying that TAFFY isn't a function. I'm not sure where the mistake is, I believe I've linked the JS files to the HTML correctly, here are all the ways I've tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/taffy-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./taffy-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="taffy-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/typicaljoe/taffydb/blob/master/taffy.js"
```

I have also tried including the full path, and for all of the above I tried it using 'taffy.js' instead of 'taffy-min.js'. I have also tried it with and without jQuery:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

I am not sure if the mistake is the JS files not linking to the HTML properly, or if it's something entirely different. Code I used to set up a user:

```
var users = TAFFY([
        {
            "id": 1,
            "user": "John123",
            "level": 5,
            "gameType: "easy"
        }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have missing double quotes here: `"gameType: "easy"`, should be `"gameType": "easy"`. The error is saying that `TAFFY` is not a function: this means that there's another variable in the scope named `TAFFY`.
In order to check if the taffy script is linked correctly open the console and type `typeof this.TAFFY` which should print `"function"`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Didn't notice that, thank you. When using `<script src="taffy.js"></script>` it prints "function", but says that TAFFY is not defined? This is where I got it from, I thought the mistake could be here, but no one else seems to be having this problem that I can find: https://github.com/typicaljoe/taffydb/blob/master/taffy.js

Comment: The taffy.js  file is OK. Did you you place it in the same  directory of the HTML file? If yes it should work.

Comment: It was, not sure where the mistake was, but I switched from Visual Studio to Web Storm, kept everything else the same and it works now. Thank you for your help